# How can I run a MySQL Administration statement with Eloquent and check results?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I'd like to perfrom a query like

"SHOW SLAVE STATUS"

with Laravel5/Eloquent ORM

What I tried is:

```
$select = DB::select("SHOW SLAVE STATUS");
```

But when I dump $select it's an empty array. Instead I expect all the data:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-slave-status.html

Comment: Please try `$select = DB::select(DB::raw("SHOW SLAVE STATUS"));`. It works for me with SQL `SHOW STATUS`. `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` did not show me any information.

Comment: I dont understant very well your comment, but If you meant to try $select = DB::select(DB::raw("SQL SLAVE STATUS")); it ends up with a MySQL syntax error

Comment: No, please try `$select = DB::select(DB::raw("SHOW SLAVE STATUS"));` as written above.

Comment: Yes it works like that, Thanks